# Why is Spynner so slow?

Tags: python, spynner

I'm currently using Spynner to load a web page a few times through a proxy. Through the debug feature, I've noticed that Spynner loads the non-local elements of a page individually and not concurrently. The webpage that I'm trying to visit is pretty heavy.

Here's an example of what I'm doing.

```
import random
import spynner

proxies = [proxy.strip() for proxy in open('proxies.txt', 'r')]

while True:
    proxy = random.choice(proxies)

    browser = spynner.Browser(debug_level=spynner.DEBUG)
    browser.set_proxy(proxy)

    browser.load("http://website.com/")

    browser.show()
    browser.browse()
    browser.close()
```

What can be a solution to this?

Comment: Does spynner have a concurrency feature built-in? I was not able to find this information, but it could be that the authors have not implemented that so far in order to keep things simple. I understand that spynner is made for testing, and not for performance. Concurrent download would implicate usage of green threads, OS-level threads or multiple processes. Any signs of these in spynners code?

Comment: Jan-Philip Gehrcke: No, I couldn't find any in the module files.

Comment: Then you might ask the authors how to speed that process up, they are the best people to ask. And if this request comes up often enough, they will maybe one day implement concurrency.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any alternate modules like this that have concurrency?